# how to solve curl: (35) error

Tags: curl, openssl, centos5

If I run in my CentOS 5 machine this command:

```
curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

I get this error:

```
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

However, if I run:

```
curl -v https://symfony.com/
```

I get this:

```
* About to connect() to symfony.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 176.34.106.156...
* Connected to symfony.com (176.34.106.156) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=Gandi Standard SSL; CN=symfony.com
*        start date: 2014-11-21 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2017-11-21 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: symfony.com matched
*        issuer: C=FR; ST=Paris; L=Paris; O=Gandi; CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: symfony.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Age: 138
< Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=600
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Sat, 07 Jan 2017 03:05:08 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
< X-Varnish: 168003559 167316902
< Content-Length: 34582
< Connection: keep-alive
<
```

With the -v option, apparently SSLv3 can be used. How to use the first command in order to successful establish the connection?

EDIT:

I have compared the curl information with a Redhat server where curl does work, and these were the results:

My CentOS 5 "curl -V" information:

```
[root@orahost tls]# curl -V
curl 7.29.0 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

The RedHat 6 "curl -V" information:

```
[root@vps-1128921-x /etc/pki/tls] # curl -V
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I notice that my CentOS uses OpenSSL while the Redhat does not. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How to fix curl sslv3 alert handshake failure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Are you on Mac OS? if so try this to re install cURL:

```
brew install curl
brew link curl --force
```

See this link for explanation:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Also try:

```
curl -LsS3 https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

adding -3 option for --sslv3.
Here's all the options for cURL in case you need it:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: I used -3 option but the same problem occurs. The problem only happen when  I use "symfony" binary to add a new project.

Comment: Maybe try wget.

Comment: As I said, that problem also happen when using "symfony" binary, so I think I need to solve the problem instead of trying to patch it. To use the curl application I have used http instead of https and it worked but this is the tip of the iceberg so maybe there is some misconfiguration in openSSL library or something like that

Comment: I have edited the question with a comparison between a server where curl does not work and a server where it does work.

Comment: I am thinking that the https server I am trying to connect to does not support either SSLv2 or SSLv3. I realized of it by performing this command: openssl s_client -connect symfony.com:443 -ssl3. When instead of ssl3 I used tls1 it connected well. So, how can I tell my system to not use SSLv3 protocol? Do you know or will it be necessary to open other question?